# Blank result for stored procedure called from codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, stored-procedures

I have created on stored procedure in mysql.

```
CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE  `test` () NOT DETERMINISTIC CONTAINS SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER BEGIN
SELECT *
FROM user
WHERE userid =2; END
```

And called it from model.

```
public function get_device_detail_sp(){
    $res = $this->db->query("CALL test()");
    return $res;
}
```

In phpmyadmin it is returning proper result but when I call it from model it is returning blank result.

Returning 1 in num_rows but result array is blank.

```
CI_DB_mysql_result Object ( [conn_id] => Resource id #19 [result_id] => Resource id #51 [result_array] => Array ( ) [result_object] => Array ( ) [custom_result_object] => Array ( ) [current_row] => 0 [num_rows] => 1 [row_data] => )
```

Comment: what is o/p of `print_r($res)` and any error?

Comment: No. It is not giving any error.print_r($res) is blank. It is printing query for result of $this->db->last_query(); but for $res it is blank.

Comment: This should not make any difference but can you please try with `$this->db->call_function('test');`

Comment: Its not working

Comment: Are you using mysql or mysqli as the database driver?

Comment: I am using mysql database driver

Comment: It is returning 1 in num_rows but result_array is blank